# Failed to get default debug keystore location - gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, intellij-idea, keystroke

When syncing my project's gradle, I get the error Failed to get default debug keystore location.

Somebody help me.

LOG:

[build.gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rofOS.png)

I read another forum and tried to see the solution, because I did not find it, or if I did, another error would appear

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJpsLVuvIs_YjtdD5lYB4uRzsMldJvJV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does it work from command line outside IDE?

Comment: in what sense outside the IDE?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you run the Gradle Task from the Command Prompt without using IDEA?
Also check out this Question - seems to be the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226982/failed-to-get-default-debug-keystore-location/